# What is the difference between knife cookbook site download and knife supermarket download in opscode chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have been working on opscode chef past 1 year. For downloading cookbooks from site, I have used both `knife cookbook site download` and `knife supermarket download` commands. Can anyone please explain, what is the difference between both the commands?

Comment: The `knife cookbook site` and `knife supermarket` commands are now literally aliased together so the code is identical.  There's historical `$REASONS` as to why we wound up with two identical commands.

Answer (score 2):

There is no longer really a difference, originally `knife cookbook site` was hardwired to use the main `supermarket.chef.io` so if you wanted to interact with a private or internal deployment of the Supermarket app you needed the plugin version. In other news: you shouldn't be using either of them, tools like Berkshelf and `chef install` are far superior.

Answer (score 1):

The `knife cookbook download` will download the cookbook from the `chef_server_url` configured in your `knife.rb` file. If there is more than one cookbook you will be given a choice which version to download. The downloaded cookbook is expanded locally on disk. This command is helpful to examine your local chef environment and dependencies.

The `'knife supermarket download` will download the cookbook contents from the Chef Supermarket. The file is gzipped and can be moved around. This is usually done if you are keeping a local copy of a shared cookbook for development before uploading to your local Chef server.

Comment: This was asking about `knife cookbook site download` not `knife cookbook download`.